# I need to reset a few text fields after successful data insertion

Tags: java, html, jsp

I need to reset all the text fields except for the first three. Should I reset here or on the java page that has the storing into database method ?

Comment: Question is not clear enough, please explain more.

Comment: Just clear the form. I suggest to start using more advanced technology, JSF at least.

Comment: I have 10 fields containing both text and drop down selection, The first three is common selection so with that i will have to enter other details keeping the first 3 values common for the rest of the entries. So after pressing submit button first 3 rows should have the same value and rest of the fields needs to be reset.

Comment: are you using jQuery in your project?

Answer (score 0):

SAVE DATA IN DATABASE WITH JQUERY AJAX. ON SUCCESS FUNCTION OF AJAX ASSIGN DEFAULT VALUES TO TEXT BOX THAT NEED TO REST